# Best way to put dash for empty field in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I populated a pdf from some fields that are coming from XML in C# code.
I have to put dash (-) for each empty field. Should I check each time if the field is empty put the dash or there is a way to do it for all the fields at once? 
What is the best way as I have 50 fields to check.

that is the code I have now:

```
   dt.LastName = (dt.LastName == null ? null : (string)individual.XPathSelectElement("AIndividual[@Type='Co-Applicant']/GivenName/LastName"));
   if (dt.LastName == null)
       dt.LastName = "-";
```

Comment: What is the Type of variable `dt`?

Comment: In your code you do the same thing twice, specifically in the first line. You can do this all in one line like so. *dt.LastName = (dt.LastName == null ? "-" : (string)individual.XPathSelectElement("AIndividual[@Type='Co-Applicant']/GivenName/LastName"));*

Comment: If the original value of `dt.LastName` is null, then you don't get a new value from the xml, but if the original value of `dt.LastName` is set, then you overwrite it from the xml.  This kind of seems backwards.  Can you verify the intended logic?

Comment: @umbreon222 this give me null when it is null and does not value instead of (-)

Comment: @Alma: That's because it only gives "-" when the original value of `dt.LastName` is `null`.  If the xml query returns null, it doesn't use "-".  Could you verify why your existing code is avoiding the xml query when the original value of `dt.LastName` is null?

Comment: @umbreon222: It will also return null if the xpath query doesn't yield a node.

Comment: @umbreon222 node is not existed in this XML so in debugging the dt.lastName is null. and I want to shod (-) in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume `dt.LastName` originally comes form the same document from another AIndividual element. In this case you could process your document using an array of XPath selectors and property setters. (Mind the code below is a rough sketch and not even compiled):

```
public class Applicant
{
    public string LastName { get; set;}
}

public void Process(XmlElement application, Applicant applicant)
{
    var selectors = new[] {
        new { 
                  Setter = new Action<Applicant, string>((t,v) => t.LastName = v), 
                  XPath = "GivenName/LastName"
            }
    };

    foreach(var selector in selectors)
    {
        var node = application.SelectSingleNode("AIndividual[@Type='PrimaryApplicant']/" + selector.XPath) ??
                        application.SelectSingleNode("AIndividual[@Type='CoApplicant']/" + selector.XPath);

        selector.Setter(applicant, node == null ? "-" : node.Value);
    }
}
```